# Photon Server：is that all the ClientPeer instance automatically run in fiber?

Tags: c#, photon

here is my comprehension of how Photon Server manage the connected client:
1.a client send a conneting request
2.on server, the instance of ApplicationBase create a PeerBase instance for this specific client

so is that Photon Server automatically run all the PeerBase instances in fiber? which means they are synchronous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think by "synchronous" you meant "sequential" as the opposite of "parallel".

Photon has a fiber per peer and a fiber per room. Fibers are processed using a thread pool.
Peer-level requests are queued in the peer's fiber and room-level requests are queued in the room's fiber.

The connection process is more complicated since it involves an initial conversation at ENet level. It's handled by the "native part" (a.k.a "Photon Core" or "Socket Server") or the OS (depending on the protocol, UDP or TCP) and done in parallel. Meaning, we can have many peers connecting at the same time.

[Further reading about how we use fibers to handle concurrency](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/server/v4/reference/faq#threading).

Comment: thanks! this is enough for my problem and corrected my previous wrong comprehension~